# Is there a significant advantage to more expensive 50mm prime lenses?

Tags: prime

I own a Nikon D3200 and I want to buy a 50mm Prime Lens. But this question is not general about Nikon. Some other brands released their own premium 50mm lenses and they are up to 5x as expensive compared to Nikon or Canon's primes.

- Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM
- Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 50 mm 1:1,4G
- Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 50 mm 1:1,8G

others:

- Sony Zeiss Planar T 50mm F1,4 ZA SSM
- Sigma 50mm F1,4 DG HSM
- Zeiss 50mm f/1.4 Planar T* ZF.2 manual focus

Is there a advantage when I spend $1000 for a 50mm prime compared to Nikon's 50mm 1.8 for $150?

Comment: Do some combination of [Why do some lenses cost so much?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/why-do-some-lenses-cost-so-much), [What is the Zeiss Planar T* 50mm lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45188/what-is-the-zeiss-planar-t-50mm-lens) and [What makes the Zeiss Otus 1.4/55 so special?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45168/what-makes-the-zeiss-otus-1-4-55-so-special) answer your question?

Comment: Is there a noticeable difference between 1.8 and 1.4 prime lenses?

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24/is-there-a-noticeable-difference-between-1-8-and-1-4-prime-lenses